Hanging power-tool holder to wood wall without studs
I have a rather basic question. I’d classify myself as a beginner who’s trying to learn how to get into DIY and wood working. It doesn’t come easy or natural to me but I’m learning slowly but surely.
My question - I have a power tool holder that is designed to support 150 lbs. I want to hang it on my garage wall but it doesn’t align to the studs. My garage wall is wood (not sure what kind or if there's an easy way to tell?).
My neighbor suggested getting a small piece of 3/4 plywood and mounting the plywood to the studs. Then mounting the power tool holder to the 3/4 inch plywood. Will that work?
Also what type of wood screws should I use? I have pictures of the power tool holder and the screws and anchor it came with below.




150lb means less than 40 pounds per screw, that's nothing to any half-decent screw. Now these screws are an unknown however, they could be very poor or not bad at all, or anything in between. Ideally you would want to test one to destruction if you will fully load the tool holder, just for peace of mind. Is there a spare provided by any chance, or just four? If there are only four then you might want to err on the side of caution and buy a box of better screws. You're sure to have future projects that will use up the remainder :-)

Thanks for the added photo, but unfortunately it's confusing without context (at least to me). It is indeed OSB and the stamp seems to say it's 1/8" twice, so I'd assume it is a double skin over a panel material (with insulation inside). You might be able to fasten directly to this, but I don't think there's any way to be sure that this would be strong enough. So I think affixing a thick plywood panel (possibly with construction adhesive) may be the way to go. You'd then simply screw into that, with screws just long enough to firmly hold in the ply but not poke through and penetrate the OSB.

@graphus The 1/8" comment stamped in black ink on the OSB is an almost universal warning on all half inch 4x8 sheets. It refers to a gap required between sheets. The half inch stuff is used for almost all the roof decking and house siding I've seen the past fifteen years. Simpson has a clip that insures this gap (https://www.strongtie.com/clipsandties_miscellaneousconnectors/pscl_clip/p/pscl). While not nearly as common, 1/4 inch OSB is available and possibly could have been used here.

@quill, good to know thanks. So if it's likely this is just standard 1/2" OSB we see everywhere. I wonder what the overall construction of the wall is?

Your picture shows an example of something mounted to the wall with screws that can handle a heavy load (but not how it's done).   At the very top of  the picture is some kitchen cabinets.  Take a look inside those cabinets.  I've hung many cabinets using what might be called "screws for hanging cabinets".  The screws are #10, about 3 inches long.  They would be driven into studs at the back of a cabinet. Reference your kitchen cabinets seen in the picture for an example. The small plywood board your neighbor speaks of may work but a similar size piece of lumber would be better, best would be a similar size piece of a hardwood.  The backs of many kitchen cabinets I've seen have thin backs except for a board running along the back.  It's that board which is usually screwed into the wall studs.
The other picture above appears to be a drywall type screw and a wallboard insert.  Neither the screw and especially that yellow insert are appropriate.  Cabinet hanging screws usually have a pan or tress type head instead of a flathead.
An additional picture showing the specific wall in question, has been added to the question.  That wall is OSB.  Except when used as subflooring, the common OSB I've seen in the USA is considered 1/2 inch (actually a bit less). If this 150 pound shelf is being installed on that wall, the OSB itself is probably strong enough to bear the sheer load.  There is a possibility this wall could be 1/4 inch OSB.  1/4 OSB is not as ubiquitous.  A quick review of the big retail home centers finds it in only one of three and then, at a price almost that of the common 1/2 inch variety. 1/4 OSB is not strong enough to support the shelf unit shown.  That bottom pine board running along the cement blocks at the bottom might have been added to insure the wall covering stays flat as 1/4 OSB might get wavy.  While the price of 1/2 and 1/4 inch OSB is close, builders buying large quantities might get discounts.  Factoring that as well as the labor cost associated with mud and tape for drywall make it builder attractive for places such as garage interiors.

Hello. Sorry if my picture was confusing. The kitchen cabinets have nothing to do with this. Just where I took the picture from. I’m hanging this on my garage wall. The screw and drywall anchor is what came with the unit. I’ll see if I can add a picture of my garage wall as well.

@Gary Dorman - actually they do have something to do with an answer.  Those kitchen cabinets are an example of something you already have that can support a lot of weight.  If they are like my personal kitchen cabinets, there is that board at the back which attaches the cabinet to the wall.  It is from such a board, actually two boards, that  provide enough backing for the mounting screws of your pictured unit.

Oh okay. My apologies . I’ll take a look. One contractor I know said to use two 1 by 4 pieces of wood and mount those to studs. Then mount unit to 1 by 4s. Is that a good option? Seems like that’s pretty similar to what you stated.

@Gary Dorman
Your contractor's comments are similar to mine.

Awesome thank you. So would I use #10 3 inch screws to mount to 1 by 4 to studs and then #10 1 inch screws to mount power tool holder to the 1 by 4s?

That is correct

"Neither the screw and especially that yellow insert are appropriate." I've sorry but you can't tell that by looking. Yes, there is a chance both are junk, but drywall screws are often NOT as brittle as commonly believed (common screws assumed to be better, "just because", are often WAY weaker). And there's zero way of knowing what kind of shear load that plug can take. Very similar looking plugs over here have stunning performance (taking weights you wouldn't believe without seeing). Which is why I now have no qualms about hanging heavy shelving directly off drywall with no stud engagement.

@GaryDorman, yes you must include a photo of the actual wall this will be mounted to or Answers are basically guesswork. If it's OSB, or plywood with decent strength, then you should have no problem at all screwing directly into it through the four provided keyhole holes, or by using some form of anchor — even common drywall anchors can be sufficient. As a rule they work even better in wooden panels than in drywall (if the thickness is the same) because of course the wood is way stronger.

I added a picture of the wall I’m drilling into. Not sure what type of wood it is. My house was built in 1995.

I think it’s OSB. Not sure how thick it is.
